# Row keep floating inside and above bootstap4 tabel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The footer row keep popup above the table how to prevent it that, the table the code above it
immediately, i have tried to use bootstrap cards instead of tabel and there was no problem I think
it's tabel issue

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">search</button>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="" aria- 
describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="row">
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">product</th>
      <th scope="col">category</th>
      <th scope="col">Date order</th>
      <th scope="col">status</th>
      <th scope="col">update</th>
      <th scope="col">remove</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
</div>

<div class="row">
<footer class="page-footer font-small blue">

  <!-- Copyright -->
  <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2020 Copyright:
    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Copyright -->

</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing `</table>` tag.

You can paste your code into https://codepen.io/pen/ and then select the HTML dropdown arrow and "Analyze HTML" to help find things like this.